# RHEL 5.3 Kickstart - How specify location of individual package in Workstation folder?

Tags: linux, rhel5, kickstart

I keep getting "package does not exist" errors during the install.

I made a kickstart ISO to create an unattended install of a RHEL 5.3 build machine for C++ software releases.  It pulls the kickstart config file from our internal web server.  This is handy; it makes it easy to test and modify without having to make a new ISO. And I plan to check it in to version control if I can get it working.

Anyway, the rpm packages are located in two folders on the disk; Client and Workstation.
The packages install fine for the ones that are physically located under the Client folder.  It cannot find those under the Workstation folder such as as doxygen and subversion complaining that packages do not exist.

Is there a way to specify the individual package location?

```
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# P A C K A G E S
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%packages
@gnome-desktop
@core
@base
@base-x
@printing
@development-tools
emacs
kexec-tools
fipscheck
xorg-x11-server-Xnest
xorg-x11-server-Xvfb

#Packages Located in Workstation Folder *** Install can not find any of these ??
bison
doxygen
gcc-c++
subversion
zlib-devel
freetype-devel
libxml2-devel
```

Answer (score 1):

The Kickstart script is already hosted on a web server, so the obvious suggestion is to create an RPM repository on there as well.

Copy your Workstation directory of packages (and repodata subdirectory) to the web server.

In the Kickstart script, point to this path as a new repo.

> repo (optional)
>
> Configures additional yum repositories that may be used as sources for package installation. Multiple repo lines may be specified.
>
> ```
> repo --name=<repoid> [--baseurl=<url>| --mirrorlist=<url>]
> ```
>
> - `--name=` — The repo id. This option is required.
> - `--baseurl=` — The URL for the repository. The variables that may be used in yum repo config files are not supported here. You may
>     use one of either this option or --mirrorlist, not both.
> - `--mirrorlist=` — The URL pointing at a list of mirrors for the repository. The variables that may be used in yum repo config files
>     are not supported here. You may use one of either this option or
>     --baseurl, not both.

[Kickstart Options](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Installation_Guide/s1-kickstart2-options.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is a key option for the kickstart config file. If you specify "key --skip" I believe it will install Client only by default. You must have a key for Workstation (which is a separate product) in order to install those rpms.

Keep in mind that keys are unique to each installation. So, if you install on five machines, you should have five subscriptions and five keys. Because you must embed the key in the kickstart config file, each machine must have its own config file.

You could try to wget the RPMs and install them in a post-install script, perhaps.

[Kickstart Options](http://www.redhat.com/docs/manuals/enterprise/RHEL-5-manual/Installation_Guide-en-US/s1-kickstart2-options.html)